# JS error object has no method addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I have following code

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
console.log(el);
el.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('hello');
}, false);
```

However, it returns an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'addEventListener'`

Why am I getting this error and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a Nodelist (an array like collection of dom nodes) and you can't attach an event listener to this. You will have to loop them and attach the event handler to the individual dom nodes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because, exactly as the error message tells you [`NodeList`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) don't have [an `addEventListener` method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Methods) You should iterate over the nodelist, and `addEventListener` to each element within – assuming that you want to add N listeners.

Alternately, [select only a single element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), and the remainder of your code will work as written.

Answer (score 8):

The method [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is a collection of nodes.

Hence you need to iterate it to attach event listeners

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
for(var i=0; i < el.length; i++){
    el[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert('hello');
    }, false);
}
```