# input.addEventListener is not a function &

Tags: javascript

Firstly, I had this code

```
var input = document.querySelector("fieldset > input");
var label = document.querySelector("fieldset > label");

input.addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
  if (label.classList.contains("label-blur")) {
    label.classList.remove("label-blur");
    label.classList.add("label-focus");
  } else {
    label.classList.add("label-focus");
  }
});

input.addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
  if (!input.value) {
    label.classList.remove("label-focus");
  } else {
    label.classList.add("label-blur");
  }
});
```

It works correctly.

Then I changed 'querySelector' on 'querySelectorAll'.
I found information, that addEventListener doesn't work with querySelectorAll ([JS error object has no method addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917343/js-error-object-has-no-method-addeventlistener)).
So the resolution is something like this:

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset > input");
var label = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset > label");


for(var i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
    if (label.classList.contains("label-blur")) {
      label.classList.remove("label-blur");
      label.classList.add("label-focus");
    } else {
      label.classList.add("label-focus");
    }
  });

  input[i].addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
    if (!input.value) {
      label.classList.remove("label-focus");
    } else {
      label.classList.add("label-blur");
    }
  });
};
```

But this way I have new mistakes:

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Please, let me know, how to resolve this problems.

I tryed this way (recommended by Conor Hastings):

```
    for(var i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
      input[i].addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
        for(var j=0; j < label.length; j++) {
          if (label[j].classList.contains("label-blur")) {
            label[j].classList.remove("label-blur");
            label[j].classList.add("label-focus");
          } else {
            label[j].classList.add("label-focus");
          }
        };
      });

      input[i].addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
        for(var j=0; j < label.length; j++) {
          if (!input.value) {
            label[j].classList.remove("label-focus");
          } else {
            label[j].classList.add("label-blur");
          }
        };
      });
    };
```

It's working better, but every 'addEventListener' works wrong. Now just "label-focus" is working. And it's working for every i (if *any* input:focus, *every* label is shown).

And 'let j=i' instead of 'for(var j=0; j < label.length; j++)' does not do anything.

Comment: `label[i]` will get you the label at the same index, although you'll need to use `let` instead of `var` so that `i` is scoped to each loop iteration.

Comment: ...also `if (input[i].value) {...`, or simply `if (this.value) {...`

Answer (score 0):

The same way you are accessing input through the `i` in the for loop you need to do with the label in order to get the label in the same index as the input in the labels NodeList

You'll also have to do the same thing inside of the input[i] event listener

```
for(var i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
    if (label[i].classList.contains("label-blur")) {
      label[i].classList.remove("label-blur");
      label[i].classList.add("label-focus");
    } else {
      label[i].classList.add("label-focus");
    }
  });

  input[i].addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
    if (!input[i].value) {
      label[i].classList.remove("label-focus");
    } else {
      label[i].classList.add("label-blur");
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: thank u, I've done it, but something's wrong. I added it in question.

Comment: input[i].value - the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".

Comment: and if i use 'input.value' - it seems to be right, console doesn't show any mistakes or errors. but labels are not showing.

Answer (score -1):

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset > input"),
    labels = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset > label");


for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var input = inputs[i],
      label = labels[i];
  input.addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
    var input = this.input,
        label = this.label;
    if (label.classList.contains("label-blur")) {
      label.classList.remove("label-blur");
      label.classList.add("label-focus");
    } else {
      label.classList.add("label-focus");
    }
  }.bind({input: input, label: label}));

  input.addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
    var input = this.input,
        label = this.label;
    if (!input.value) {
      label.classList.remove("label-focus");
    } else {
      label.classList.add("label-blur");
    }
  }.bind({input: input, label: label}));
};
```

If you are using ES6, then you should use let instead of var after the for loop

Comment: Are you sure this is really going to work? When the anonymous function is executed, `input` will have the final value.

Comment: The bind after the function will make it the anonymous function receive the correct value ... plz try again!