# document.querySelectorAll and document.getElementsByClassName event handling

Tags: javascript, loops

I can't assign an event handler to an element through `document.querySelectorAll` through a loop of each item in the return result. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It looks like this:

```
// divs to show/hide
const mobileNavOpen = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav-open");
const mobileNavClose = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav-close");

// mobile menu/search overlay
const mobileNavItems = document.getElementById("global-nav--mobile");
const searchOverlay = document.getElementById("search-overlay");

// search unit open/close buttons

// this line I think is broken
const navSearch = document.querySelectorAll(".global-nav__search-icon");

// this one doesn't work either
const navSearch = document.getElementsByClassName("global-nav__search-icon");

const searchCloseButton = document.querySelector(".search-overlay__close");


function mobileOpen(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  mobileNavItems.classList.add("show");
}

function mobileClose(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  mobileNavItems.classList.remove("show");
}

function searchOpen(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  searchOverlay.classList.add("show");
}

function searchClose(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  searchOverlay.classList.remove("show");
}

mobileNavOpen.addEventListener("click", mobileOpen);
mobileNavClose.addEventListener("click", mobileClose);

for (var i = 0; i < navSearch.length; i++) {
  navSearch.addEventListener("click", searchOpen);
}

searchCloseButton.addEventListener("click", searchClose);
```

Markup:

```
<nav id="global-nav">
    <a href="#" class="mobile-nav-open">+</a>
    <a class="global-nav__logo" href="/"><img src="/images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    <img class="global-nav__search-icon mobile-search" src="images/search-icon.png" alt="" style="height: 32px;">
    <ul class="global-nav__items">
      <li><a href="/item1">item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/item2">item 2</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">item 3</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">item 4</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="global-nav__items" id="login-signup">
      <li class="global-nav__search-icon"><img src="images/search-icon.png" alt=""></li>
      <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I found this answer: [JS error object has no method addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917343/js-error-object-has-no-method-addeventlistener) and am implementing the example but am still having issues.

This is supposed to be easy, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing the index in your loop (`[i]`)

```
for (var i = 0; i < navSearch.length; i++) {
    navSearch[i].addEventListener("click", searchOpen);
}
```

Note: `querySelectorAll` and `getElementsByClassName` should both do the trick. They return a NodeList or a HTMLCollection (respectively), but both support simple for loops like you did.

Comment: Howcome I didn't get any errors in the console suggesting that I missed `[i]`?

Comment: shouldn't that throw `undefined` and break the loop?

Comment: Didn't you get an error saying "object has no method addEventListener"?